# WPF application upgrade from PRISM 2 to PRISM 4.

Tags: wpf, prism, upgrade

in our derived Bootstrapper class (from UnityBootrapper) we did the following in Prism2:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer ()
{

//......more code here


foreach (Configuration config in this.configurations)

{
  if (config == null)
     continue;

  UnityConfigurationSection serviceSection =  (UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("Services");

 serviceSection.Containers.Default.Configure(container);
}

//.....more code here
}
```

Now, with Prism 4, it will not work any more:

- the class 'UnityConfigurationSection' is not declared any more by prism; there is only a 'ConfigurationSection' - class

but without a container-property.

I did not find any upgrade information to get our code running with the new prism framework.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The older PRISM syntax in `App.config` mentions `UnityConfigurationSection` explicitly

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity> 
...
...
  </unity>
...
...
</configuration>
```

now with both Unity and MEF it should be

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism"/>
  </configSections>    
  <modules>
...
...
  </modules>
...
...
</configuration>
```